# XML generated by xstream.toXml() is printing to one line

Tags: java, xml, file, output, xstream

Can anyone tell me why when I open my .XML file generated by XStream.toXML().. The XML appears on ONE line. Yet when I cut and paste it here into this form it looks just like it should, nicely formatted.

I need the generated file to look just like the output printed to the console.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. I'm thinking it has something to do with encoding but I'm not sure how to set the encoding for my file output.

Thank you!

EDIT: I was able to get the text displaying correctly by running a replace on the string. "\n" for "\r\n"

The problem is I'm having trouble understanding how and why XStream doesn't do this for me?

Comment: In what application are you opening the XML file? Have you tried, for example, opening it with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)? Some editors support only a restricted set of linebreaks and do not display other linebreaks (that are e.g. common in the Linux world) correctly.

Comment: It's the application that chooses to nicely format the xml in whatever format it works with (e.g. html in a browser). So what are you opening it with?

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I've been using plain old notepad because that is what will be available to use. I've read that notepad only accepts CR/LF as its linebreaks. Any Idea how I can alter the toXML() output to conform to the CR/LF so it will look right in notepad?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Notepad actually doesn't recognize a lot of typical linebreak formats, from my experience. Try Sublime Text 2, which is my primary text editor these days. It will save your eyes.